# Should application-defined message IDs be unique?

Tags: windows, winapi

I often have to use the event model in an application based on Windows messages to notify the main thread of the application about some of the results of other threads. This approach allows you to get rid of blocking between threads.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues) says that system message IDs must be unique. But I did not find such a condition for application messages. At the same time, very often on the Internet you can find the opinion that within the application, message identifiers must be unique.

I see no point in being unique within the application. When sending a message, we specify a specific window handle that should process the message. I can use the same message ID in different windows, but it is the window handle that determines the recipient of the message. And it works.

Are there any obvious reasons to keep track of the uniqueness of message IDs in the application?

Comment: The combination message + wparam + lparam is yours, you do what you want with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no requirement that all message IDs be unique within an application. In fact, we are using multiply assigned message IDs all the time: [WM_USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-user)-based messages are used by window classes to implement class-specific behavior. The most prominent example are the [Common Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/common-controls-intro) that implement control-specific behavior using the `[WM_USER..WM_APP)` range of message IDs.

If you are calling `RegisterClassEx` you opt in to using `WM_USER`-based messages. You are free to reuse any value used by a different window class without risking a collision. It's the combination of the receiving window's class and the message ID that controls the behavior.

If you don't have a receiver (e.g. when calling `PostThreadMessage`) you would need to make sure that you can uniquely identify a message (and its payload). The easiest way in this case is to use *unique* message IDs in the [WM_APP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-app) range.

Comment: `PostThreadMessage` sends a message to the receiving thread using the `idThread` parameter.

Comment: Well, it *posts* a message to the specified thread's message queue. Thread message IDs need to be unique per thread.